# How to determinate the file extension if it isn't at the end of the url

Tags: java, android

I've got this URL (http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/fantendo/images/6/6e/Small-mario.png/revision/latest?cb=20120718024112)

how determinate the file extension if it isn't at the end of the url?

Comment: You would need to know the rules for the given site. After all, in your URL above, `.png` is not necessarily a file extension. For all I know, it is four randomly-chosen characters that happen to map to a common file extension.

Comment: If you have the image bytes (from the URL), you can analyze the magic number of the bytes (The first few bytes of the file) and determine the extension from that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: there is that http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromStream%28java.io.InputStream%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to read the response headers. The MIME Type if known is stored in the `Content-Type` header.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="Small-mario.png"
X-Thumbnailer: Vignette
Content-Type: image/png
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
X-Surrogate-Key: ad1f82ba0cbe38fa60f83c036993a71e05dae492
Server: Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)
X-Cacheable: YES
Content-Length: 58457
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Mon, 06 Jul 2015 16:12:31 GMT
Age: 65
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: thumbnailer-s1, cache-wk-sjc3160-WIKIA, cache-lhr6322-LHR
X-Cache: ORIGIN, MISS, HIT
X-Cache-Hits: ORIGIN, 0, 5
X-Timer: S1436199151.564330,VS0,VE0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Timing-Allow-Origin: *
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `Content-Type` header, which the server ought to send in the HTTP response to tell you this.

Note that it is not guaranteed to be accurate, or present at all.